# which conducting pattern is this?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, beats, choir, conducting

the Indian national anthem is conducted on this pattern. I want to know more about it.
the baton starts from the top...goes down...back up....back down......and now to the outer side...back in.....out again...back in....repeat.
to understand you may view 




here, an officer is conducting this pattern.
what is it...2/4 3/4 6/8 12/8.....I mean could you give more information about this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

It's plain old 4/4 time, and the baton goes down on 1, left on 2, right on 3 and back up on 4, as usual. Look *really* carefully!

Comment: That's right. If you look  90° from the left you can see another different pattern. That's why the conductor usually stands in front of the band. (But the intonation won't be better!)